# How mix third input of the MixRGB node

Tags: python

```
node = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB') 
node.location = (1,1)
node.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Color 3')
node.blend_type = ('MIX')
node.inputs[1].default_value = (0.5,0,0,1)
node.inputs[2].default_value = (0,0.5,0,1)
node.inputs[3].default_value = (0,0,1,1)
```

MixRGB node by default mix only two data but how fore it to mix more than two (three for the instance). Now I get nothing from the output

Comment: Hello! I'm afraid it's not possible to do that. Besides, how would it work since you have only 1 factor field ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yea factor is the problem here, so, actually, I need a distinct factor for each member of the equation like: output = Input[1]*f1 + Input[2]*f2 + Input[3]*f3 (where f1+f2+f3=1). But seems it is impossible by the nature of the MixRGB node, likely you right

Comment: You can approach it by using 3 mix shader nodes and adding everything at the end eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g9Fw.png

Answer (score 4):

You can make a custom shader group, for example, below a group that mixes all given colors equally - notice how you need to tell it how many colors are passed - otherwise it can't distinguish between a default value and a connected input (you could use a [Sentinel Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) with a risk that some texture or procedure will yield this exact color).

[image]

[image]

If you just want to specify factors, that makes the setup quite simple, since unused colors can have a default factor of `0`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It does give the result. In fact, I should make it through a script but I have gotten a clue, then it's up to me